# Why is it harder to fill at the mid-point with my new broker?

Tags: options, schwab

My old broker (USAA) sold my accounts to Schwab.  When I used USAA, I would buy options at around the mid-point, usually.  The order would be filled quickly.  Now that I am using Schwab, I mostly never get filled at the mid-point.  I'll have to wait and bump up my bid a few times before the order will be filled.  What changed between USAA and Schwab?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Getting a fill at the midpoint is a function of there being a  counterparty willing to transact at that price whether it be the market maker or another trader.  That has nothing to do with who your broker is.  One broker can't give you a better price than another - they're just submitting orders to the option exchanges.

I have found that in some stocks whose options that I trade, the market makers split the bid more often than not.  And in  others, they won't even budge a nickel on a 25 cent or wider B/A spread.  Chances are, you're either trading options with lower liquidity now or you're involved in some of these "won't budge" options.

Comment: Bob, but can't it be also a function of which broker is used?  Isn't something along these lines how Robin Hood makes money?

Comment: If BEST & COMPANY could get better prices on executions than other brokers, wouldn't everyone open accounts at BEST? Wouldn't all of the other brokers replicate what BEST is doing, akin to most discount brokers going to zero commissions last year when IBKR went to zero? Robinhood makes money on cash balances in accounts as well as payment for order flow for routing orders to firms like Citadel and Virtu which arb profits from the executed transactions. None of this gives the trader a better price on his order to buy or sell a security unless maker rebates are passed on which AFAIK, RH doesn't.

Comment: Bob I've accepted your answer as it's practical and likely, in most cases.  But I still believe something's going on here.  It's statistically very improbably that nearly all my dozens of mid-point orders with one broker would go through, whereas nearly none with the new broker would go through.  Minuscule probability.

Comment: It's statistically improbable that the Super Bowl Indicator would be more than 90% effective at the 30 year mark (original NFL team wins the SB) and yet it was.  Sometimes, random numbers just line up that way.  Just a repeat but brokers submit orders to the stock and option exchanges.  They don't determine the price. NBBO does.

Comment: They don't line up that way repeatedly.  We can go through a "Let pf be the probability that..." exercise but no need to flush out what's obvious.  Another possible point of interest: partial fills are frequent on Schwab, they were infrequent with USAA.

Comment: You can argue this until the cows come home but the simple fact here is that the broker is an order taker that forwards orders to the exchanges.  NBBO is determined bt the auction participants (traders and/or market makers) and it dictates fill price.  If a counter party is willing to take the other side, you get a fill.  No counterparty, no fill.  A sort of exception would be combo orders.  I say sort of because the spread's quote is NBBO so it adheres to the explanation but the individual legs might be filled b/t their actual B/A quotes (still requires a willing counterparty).

Answer (score 0):

The broker *does* make a difference here usually: the way the relationship between market makers, buying and selling order flow and the HFTs work on this information is fairly simple: they are looking for uninformed money where they can be relatively certain they are not trading with uninformed participants and make a reliable profit on the spread.

Say you are market making a volatile stock prone to inside information that trades at a very wide spread of say $10.0 vs $12.0. Market makers here with public bids in the order book have to trade both wide spreads and low liquidity to protect themselves from informed investors of size hoovering up one side and leaving them holding the bag.

However, they would be perfectly happy trading at a much narrower spread (and higher liquidity) if they knew the person(s) making the trade were uninformed, say just above/below the mid point at $10.90/$11.10. Using the order flow information they quickly see the order is from a broker without big and smart customers and jump in to match you at the mid point if your bid is anywhere near these ranges. Because of this, you will often get different fills from different brokers on mid point trades depending on how these algos evaluate the traffic and if they can even see what broker (eg some brokers don't sell order flow) it came from and it's size etc.

What is strange about this is specific situation is that Schwab is a major seller of order flow so unless they have a much higher % of skilled options traffic (which would make that order flow less valuable/trustworthy) than USAA did, it doesn't make a lot of sense in this exact situation as usually Schwab's sale of this order flow helps small customers via lots of price improvement.

Overall it is fairly common to see a big difference on small orders matching between brokers when submitting near the mid point as you describe due to the reasons above, but this exact specific one doesn't make much sense unless your order size or pattern has changed a lot, or something like USAA or a USAA affiliate was themselves matching your bids as a market maker.

Comment: You described many market underpinnings and a lot of what ifs: A $2 wide spread, how HFTs operate, uninformed money, a market maker's willingness to trade at a narrower spread, a broker without big and smart customers, whether a broker sells order flow, and a conclusion that "this exact specific one doesn't make much sense unless your order size or pattern has changed a lot, or something like USAA or a USAA affiliate was themselves matching your bids as a market maker." I don't see how any of this gives a trader any insight as to how a broker gets better fills and how to find that broker.

Comment: There isn't a simple answer to that question unless you know a lot about the trader. An uniformed low stakes option trader will get vastly better fills on small orders with people like Robin Hood who sell order flow vs someone trying to move millions a day with an edge in markets who will get hurt by these structures. As I state, this example doesn't make much sense given the brokers mentioned but the answer to the underlying key question that your broker (and changing broker) can make a big difference to fill price is correct.